# How to Clone XSSFCell in Apache POI

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi

My Code:
How to Clone `XSSFCell` in `Apache POI` - when am Iterating the row in loop i just want to `clone/copy` present `XSSFCell` and want to do some changes in newly created Cell .

```
          XSSFRow myRow = (XSSFRow)rowIter.next();
          Iterator cellIter = myRow.cellIterator();
          List cellRowList = new ArrayList();

          while (cellIter.hasNext()) 
          {
              XSSFCell myCell = (XSSFCell)cellIter.next();
              try
             {
                XSSFCell newCell = myCell //( How to clone or copy a new one)

             } catch(Exception e) {
                syso(e);
             }             

           }
```

Comment: What are you going to do with this cloned cell? Do you mean you want to make a different cell have the same style? Same value? Same style+value?

Comment: I want exactly style cell but with different Cell value,so i tried to clone and set a new value (instead of creating new Workbook, sheet ,row & cell - trying to clone it )

Comment: I skipped rest of my codes - after read the cell value i'll  put in to collection and do my operations

Comment: What poi version do you use?

Answer (score 0):

You may use cloneStyleFrom to clone the style from the original workbook.

```
XSSFRow myRow = (XSSFRow) rowIter.next();
Iterator cellIter = myRow.cellIterator();
List cellRowList = new ArrayList();

while (cellIter.hasNext()) {
    XSSFCell originalCell = (XSSFCell) cellIter.next();
    XSSFCell myCell = originalCell;
    try {
        // XSSFCell newCell = myCell; //( How to clone or copy a new one)
        XSSFCellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle(); // the XSSFWorkbook from which you clone
        style.cloneStyleFrom(originalCell.getCellStyle());
        myCell.setCellStyle(style);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        syso(e);
    }
}
```